# UISearchBar and TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hey everbody, im trying to make work a UISearchView, with a table view. Im getting the data of table with TBXML, parsing some xml from a php.

When i set to show me on log the results, it gives me, but dont add to table view my results.
What im doing wrong?

```
@synthesize tableData;

@synthesize theSearchBar;
@synthesize theTableView;
@synthesize resultados;

//View load

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableData =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.theSearchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

// Search

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    self.theTableView.allowsSelection = NO;
    self.theTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    searchBar.text=@"";

    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    self.theTableView.allowsSelection = YES;
    self.theTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {




    NSString *endereco = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://localhost/icomm/test.php?nome=%@", searchBar.text];


    TBXML * tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:endereco]] retain];
    TBXMLElement * rootXMLElement = tbxml.rootXMLElement;

    TBXMLElement * item = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"item" parentElement:rootXMLElement];

    resultados = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    while (item) {

        NSString * produtoNome = [TBXML textForElement:item];

        NSLog(@"%@", produtoNome);


        [resultados addObject:produtoNome];

        item = [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:@"item" searchFromElement:item
                      ];


    }



    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
   [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
   self.theTableView.allowsSelection = YES;
    self.theTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    [self.tableData removeAllObjects];
    //[self.tableData addObjectsFromArray:resultados];
    [self.theTableView reloadData];
}


// Table


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [resultados count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"SearchResult";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                 reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *nomeProd = [resultados objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = nomeProd;

    return cell;
}


//Dealloc

- (void)dealloc {
    [theTableView release], theTableView = nil;
    [theSearchBar release], theSearchBar = nil;
    [tableData dealloc];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to store your search results in another array, and tell your datasource to show search results when searching.